# Delete table column if exists (SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax error or access violation)

Tags: mysql

I need to delete one table column if it exists, but i have some problems.. I'm keep getting this error and i can't figure it out why

```
An error occurred when processing the migration:
  Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_d' at line 1
```

This is my query

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_Name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my__table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'currency_format'))
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE 'my__table' DROP COLUMN currency_format;  
END
```

Phpmyadmin SQL console is also reporting errors
[image]

So, what to do so i will be able to execute this query?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made workaround with the following code and its working now

```
set @exist_Check := (
select count(*) from information_schema.columns
where TABLE_NAME='my__table'
and COLUMN_NAME='currency_format'
and TABLE_SCHEMA='my_db_Name'
);
set @sqlstmt := if(@exist_Check>0,'alter table my__table drop column currency_format', 'select ''''') ;
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt ;
execute stmt ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to unquote your tablename in your ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
IF (SELECT 1=1 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_Name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my__table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'currency_format') THEN
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE my__table DROP COLUMN currency_format;  
END IF;
```